# MacPorts: How do I rebuild of a specific port?

Tags: macports, osx-mountain-lion, qt

How do I force MacPorts to rebuild a specific port? I manually made a change to a MacPorts makefile to link in a specific library, but the missing symbol still cannot be found. Perhaps I need to rebuild, but how do I accomplish that without cleaning out the port (which deletes the file I modified)?

#### Motivation

Using MacPorts, I'm trying to install Qt (i.e., the `qt4-mac-devel` port) in Mac OS X Mountain Lion,
but it fails with an undefined symbol (`_objc_msgSend_fixup`). A [MacPorts ticket](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/35313#comment:11) with a similar problem
led me to inspect the offending `QtWebKit.pro` file under:

```
QT4_SRC=/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_aqua_qt4-mac-devel/qt4-mac-devel/work/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.0/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/WebKit/qt/
```

The `else` predicate on line 254 checks for Darwin 11 or the 10.7 SDK (both of which are in Lion and unavailable in Mountain Lion).
There is no predicate in the `if-else` list for Mountain Lion's WebKit.

```
254:  } else: equals(DARWIN_MAJOR_VERSION, "11") | contains(QMAKE_MAC_SDK, "/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk") {
255:    LIBS += $$SOURCE_DIR/../WebKitLibraries/libWebKitSystemInterfaceLion.a
256:  }
257:}
```

As a *dirty quick fix*, I changed line 254 to be an unconditional `else`. When I try to test this by re-running the `port install`
command, I see the same original error. I'm pretty sure MacPorts is not even looking at my change because I reran the command after entering garbage text into the file and renaming the file. So, I'm now looking for a way to force the rebuild.

#### Things I've tried

- Rebuild with the [`-s`](http://www.puredarwin.org/developers/macports/port) flag (to rebuild from source): `sudo port install -s qt4-mac-devel`
- Rebuild after touching all Qt source files: `find ${QT4_SRC} -name "*.cpp" -exec touch {} \;`
- Clean the port and then rebuild (no go...`port clean` deletes the `QtWebKit.pro` file, which contains my necessary changes)

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of Stack Overflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690159/sneaky-patching-source-with-macports/11907135

Answer (score 2):

I would advise to create a local portfile for qt4-mac-devel and add your changes as a patch that is applied during the build process.

1. Create a local portfile repository: [howto](http://guide.macports.org/#development.local-repositories)
2. Copy the qt4-mac-devel portfile directory (a directory called "qt4-mac-devel" (path "/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/ports/aqua/qt4-mac-devel/") containing the file "Portfile" and directory "files") into your local portfile repository
3. Create a patch with your changes of the qt4-mac-devel source code and add it to the "files" directory.
4. Edit your local qt4-mac-devel Portfile to include the line `patchfiles yourpatch.diff`
5. Run `portindex` again in your local portfile repository
6. Install qt4-mac-devel with `port install -s qt4-mac-devel`

I hope this can help.